# How to concatenate two countVectorizers?

Tags: python, concatenation, text-classification, n-gram, countvectorizer

I'm using text classification to identify dialects. I'm using sklearn and countVectorizer, I want to train naive bayes classifier on both character-based ngrams and vocabularies. So I have the following settings on two countVectorizers:

```
c=CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2,3))
c.fit_transform(X_train)

v=CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabs)
v.fit_transform(X_train)
```

Where do I go from there? I tried this:

```
numpy.concatenate([c,v])
```

as was suggested in this post:
[How to use bigrams + trigrams + word-marks vocabulary in countVectorizer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56083449/how-to-use-bigrams-trigrams-word-marks-vocabulary-in-countvectorizer)

but didn't work